# ag grid won't show correctly in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying  to use ag-grid bu the result is not correct I don't know what is the problem
this is my HTML code

```
<p>user-access works!</p>
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" class="ag-theme-balham" [rowData]="rowData"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

this is ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-access',
  templateUrl: './user-access.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-access.component.css']
})
export class UserAccessComponent implements OnInit {

  columnDefs = [
    {headerName:'make',field: 'make' },
    {headerName:'model',field: 'model' },
    {headerName:'price',field: 'price'}
];

rowData = [
    { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 }
];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

this is CSS

```
@import  "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import  "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
```

I add these imports to style.css too but the result is not ok
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Everything looks fine, except it seems you are using the imports intended for SCSS files in styles.css

You should add the following lines if you are using SCSS in styles.scss:

```
@import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
```

If you are importing the themes via CSS, then add this in your index.html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no prior experience with ag-Grid, but it seems to be directly copied from their [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world) which seems to be working. Since the things you've shown us looks the same (beside them using .scss and you having .css styles), I would look in other places:

If it doesn't seem to work correctly for you, verify that you have the same version of both `ag-grid-angular` and `ag-grid-community` in your `package.json' file. Perhaps re-run npm install to make sure both packages are actually installed.

Try navigating to the path from which you are serving the ng-grid .css files and make sure they are physically there.

Make sure there are no errors thrown in console when you are loading the application.
Make sure there are no errorcs in the angular CLI console when it rebuilds the application.

Comment: Try reproducing the issue on stackblitz then. If that fails, push the full project to public git repository and let others run in locally so that they can try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this i think your css import path is not correct.

```
@import "~@ag-grid-community/core/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "~@ag-grid-community/core/dist/styles/ag-theme-fresh/sass/ag-theme-fresh.css";
```

Comment: no, it is not the problem I did this and I got an error

Answer (score 0):

The correct files to load are located in ag-grid-community/styles or @ag-grid-community/styles if you're using modules.

This path has changed in v28, and the old files are still there as part of the Legacy Styles but will be removed in v29.

to learn more, https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/themes/

Answer (score 0):

What I needed to do is put the links in the **global** styles.css file for my Angular app. That and also making sure we're not using the 'dist' folder as part of that path like @Shekhar had mentioned.

`@import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';`

`@import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';`